# How to search for any repeating character, X number of times

Tags: regular-expression, search, find

Let's say a buffer has a certain characters I know will be repeated seven (7) times. How can I search for *any* character repeated seven times?

I know I can search for `..`, but those to characters won't necessarily be the same. There's also a special character (not sure if it's `&`) that can be used in substitutions to paste the found string in the replacement field, but I'm also not sure if that's useable again here.

EDIT:
I'm specifically searching for merge conflict markers from git (`<<<<<<<`, `=======`, or `>>>>>>>` - possibly `|||||||`), but I'd like to know how to perform this search for *any* character X, repeating N times, so that I may reapply the knowledge in the future.

Thanks to @DJMcMayhem for the suggestion of vimregex.com; it lead me to search for `/\v<<<<<|=====|>>>>>` which caused an error, as each of those are special characters. Escaping those, however (`/\v\<\<\<\<\<|\=\=\=\=\=|\>\>\>\>\>`) did succeed in finding what I was looking for, *in the short term*. I'm still looking for a way to search for character X, repeating N times.

Answer (score 16):

There's two different regex features that would be helpful. First off, you can use capturing groups. If you put something in parentheses, you can refer to whatever matched inside. So

```
/\(.\)\1
```

Will match *any character* (`\(.\)`) followed by that same character (Group 1, `\1`). You can also refer to groups in the replacement part of a substitute command.

The other feature is quantifiers.

- `\{n,m}`
  matches from n to m of the preceding characters...
- `\{n}`
  matches exactly n times of the preceding characters...
- `\{,m}`
  matches at most m (from 0 to m) of the preceding characters...
- `\{n,}`
  matches at least n of of the preceding characters...

putting it all together, you want to use:

```
/\(.\)\1\{6}
```

Or as the way I'd prefer it,

```
/\v(.)\1{6}
```

---

I'd recommend reading through [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/). It's a good tutorial on vim regex features.

Comment: This didn't seem to work (either with or without that final `\` that seems to be optional). I am searching for git diff indicators, which are `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, or `>>>>>>>`. {I believe `|||||||` is also used if it is a three-way merge, but don't know for sure.}
Your suggestion of vimregex.com was valuable though; see my updated question.

Comment: @user3.1415927 I'm not sure what to tell you. `/\(.\)\1\{6}` will *definitely* match any one character repeated 7 times, so there must be something else at play. And I did answer the question "How do I search for a character repeated N times": use `\{n}` Also your example regex doesn't seem right, each character is repeated only 5 times.

Comment: To add to that, your regex could be a lot cleaner if you used the quantifiers I mentioned. For example, `/\v\<{7}|\={7}|\>{7}` (or `{5}` if you want something equivalent to the one you posted)