# how to find the all the lines where they are the same like A(A)(A), B(B)(B), Z(Z)(Z)?

Tags: search

For example:

```
sfdAAAzsd
sdfBBBadf
sd1ZZZsdf
```

Hightlighted:

```
sfd"AAA"zsd
sdf"BBB"adf
sd1"ZZZ"sdf
```

all letters will be searched only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inspired from [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19281/how-to-search-for-any-repeating-character-x-number-of-times), we can search with

```
/\([A-Z]\)\1\{2}
```

Here is what the pattern after `/` does:

- `[A-Z]` match any uppercase letter A to Z
- `\(...\)` capture this (what is within `\(` and `\)`) and possibly refer to it later
- `\1` refer to the first item captured with `\(...\)`
- `\{2}` match 2 of the preceding items (`\1` in this case)

Thus the pattern above will match `AAA,BBB,...,ZZZ`.

To print the lines that match {pattern} we can use the `:g[lobal]` command, that is

```
:g/{pattern}/
```

We can omit {pattern} to use the last used search pattern, ie.

```
:g//
```